# Redirecting without refreshing every 10 seconds

Tags: html

I want to redirect my page to another page using HTML but when I try to use the method that everyone suggested me: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=http://zacharycabal.tumblr.com/tagged/b&w">`, the webpage refreshes every 10 second which make it look bad.

Is there a possible way to make it redirect and then never refresh again?

Comment: What method did everyone suggest to you?

Answer (score 1):

Use of meta refresh [is discouraged](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) by W3C. So it is recommended to use server redirect instead. JavaScript redirects may not work on mobile, since JavaScript might be disabled. I think the best way, if possible, is to use server redirects, so send a 301 in the header. This is easy to do via .htaccess.

Also, in some cases the browser can ignore 0 values. I think a proper approach could be an html refresh and a javascript redirect. But of course is better using server side:

```
<head>
...
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://zacharycabal.tumblr.com/tagged/b&w">
      <script language="javascript">
          window.location.href = "http://zacharycabal.tumblr.com/tagged/b&w""
      </script>
...
</head>
```

In case PHP is an option:

```
<?php
  header("Location: http://zacharycabal.tumblr.com/tagged/b&w"", TRUE, 301);
  exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you include a little Javascript within your `<body>` tag:

```
<body onload="location.href = 'http://zacharycabal.tumblr.com/tagged/b&w';">
  ...
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
       <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="10;url=http://www.pagenamehere.com">
```

You can also include a message in the body that the page is redirecting, and a link in case it does not.